# Generating sonar report for 5.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

My requirement is to run jenkins job that will invoke sonar analysis.
This was achieved.

Now all I want is to generate a PDF report and send that report through email.
On analysis, I came across "sonar-report-plugin" to achieve this.
As per the below documentation, i need to run "sonar-runner report" command to achieve the desired result.
but for sonar 5.2 Tasks are no more supported on batch side so the above command fails to execute and just running the "sonar-runner" does not generate the PDF on the specified dashboard.

The documentation i refereed to is "http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/installation-and-usage/"

please advise what can i do to get the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PDF Report](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report) plugin is not compatible with SonarQube 5.2 (see [Plugin Version Matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) and [issue to resolve problems with 5.1](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report/issues/8)) and is marked as deprecated (see [Deprecated Plugins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Deprecated+Plugins)):

> [**PDF Report**](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report) - Generates PDF report from project analysis. Note that
>   report is not configurable and cannot be sent by email and the plugin
>   is limited to Java Maven projects.

Comment: thanks for the help.
is there any other workaround to get the PDF or do i need to swtich to earlier version of sonarqube?

Comment: There is a commercial [Report](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/) plugin, but for now it is not compatible with SonarQube 5.2.